# Live Rectangle detection using Vision Framework

Tags: ios, swift, camera, rectangles, vision

I'm trying to detect rectangle from live preview layer, but not able to detect all rectangles.

***What I'm doing***

*To setup Vision Request*

```
 func setupVision() {
    let rectanglesDetectionRequest = VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangles)
    rectanglesDetectionRequest.maximumObservations = 0
    rectanglesDetectionRequest.quadratureTolerance = 45.0
    rectanglesDetectionRequest.minimumAspectRatio = 0.64
    self.requests = [rectanglesDetectionRequest]
}

    
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
        return
    }
    
    let exifOrientation = self.exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        var requestOptions: [VNImageOption : Any] = [:]
        
        if let cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil) {
            requestOptions = [.cameraIntrinsics: cameraIntrinsicData]
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation:exifOrientation, options: requestOptions)
            do {
                try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        

    }
    

    var arr = Array<VNTrackRectangleRequest>()
    for obs in self.rectanglesss{
            let trackRequest = VNTrackRectangleRequest(rectangleObservation: obs, completionHandler: self.handleSequenceRequestUpdate)
            trackRequest.trackingLevel = .accurate
            arr.append(trackRequest)
    }
    
    
    do {
        try self.sequenceHandler.perform(arr, on: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong ?
When I try with Right angle sometimes it detect few of them, with Acute angle its detect only near by 2-3 rectangles. Here I try with SET cards, I added 2images of what I'm getting.

**Result**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try iphone to see them via bird view? And get a different table with non-white color

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put your phone flat and shoot ,then setting minimumConfidence

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectrectanglesrequest/2875373-maximumobservations

```
let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in
    // Your completion handler code
}

request.maximumObservations = 2
```